# Convert text file input to array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert text file input to an array in PHP.

**Here is my text file sample input:**

```
Name:abc
Age: 50
Address:
         Postal:123
          City:and
DOB:1/5/1996
```

**Array in PHP should be (Output):**

```
[name]->ABC
[AGE]->50
[ADDRESS][POSTAL]->123
[Address][city]=and
[DOB]=1/5/1996
[DOB][time]->8:20
```

**or as**

```
Array(1)
[Name]=>ABC
[Age]=>50
[Address]==>  Array(2)
                          [City]=>and
Array(1)
[DOB]=>1/5/1996
                 Array(2)
                   [Time]=>8:20
```

**I truly don't have any clue. Please help me get desired output. PHP code to implement this.**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: And where are you stuck?

Comment: Please provide actual php code

Comment: @HoloHokkaido - done. Please have a look.

Comment: @Emily, why this fragment `product:
  sku: BL394D
  quantity: 4` is missed from the expected output you have presented?

Comment: Why do you `print` outside of `for` loop ?

Comment: @HoloHokkaido Sorry, i don't have any clue about this. Basic PHP is in my course syllabus. And i have to complete this question as my assignment to get those marks. Please someone provide PHP code to do this.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest : Please have a look at my sample input and output again. I would be very thankful if you can provide me the code to implement this.

Comment: `[DOB][time]->8:20` have not been included in your sample input, why does it appear in the output? Solve that discrepancy and then, I'll go about some solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will works for you.(how's it works is added as comment):-

```
<?php

define('CHARS',4); //constant to remind yaml spec for number of spaces.

$input = "Name:abc
Age: 50
Address:
         Postal:123
          City:and
DOB:1/5/1996";

$inarray = explode("\n",$input); // explode with new line
echo "<pre/>";print_r($inarray); // print array
$final_array = array(); // create final empty array
$child_array = ''; // an empty variable
foreach ($inarray as $key=>$inarra){ // loop iteration
    $identSize = strlen($inarra)-strlen(ltrim($inarra)); // check that original value have any spaces at thhe begning or not?
    $explode_data = explode(':',$inarra); // explode with :
    if($identSize == 0){ // if original string have no spaces at the begning
        $child_array = trim($explode_data[0]); // asssign its first value to newely created variable
        $final_array[trim($explode_data[0])] = trim($explode_data[1]); // add key value pair to final array
    }else{
        $final_array[$child_array][trim($explode_data[0])] = trim($explode_data[1]); // add key value pair as an subarray to the prevously created index which have no space at the begning
    }
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/587362

Answer (score 0):

You need to save somewhere the parent key when the value is an empty string. This way, you can use it on the next iteration when you hit a key that starts with an empty character.

```
<?php
$input = "Name:abc
Age: 50
Address:
         Postal:123
         City:and
DOB:1/5/1996";

$values = [];
$parent_key = '';
foreach (explode("\n", $input) as $line) {
  list($key, $value) = explode(":", $line);
  if ($key[0] == ' ')
    $values[trim($parent_key)][trim($key)] = $value;
  else {
    $parent_key = $key;
    $values[trim($key)] = $value;
  }
}

print_r($values);
?>
```